# Assigning to a dataset that could only be found through another list

Tags: r

I have a list of dataset names in a list that does not contain actual datasets themselves. How do I assign to a specific dataset another dataset?

Example:

- data[1] contains the name of a dataset1.
- data[2] contains the name of a dataset2.

I want to assign dataset2 to dataset1.

get(data[1]) <- get(data[2]) does not working.

How do I solve the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IF you really, really want to do that you could use `assign`:

```
assign(data[1], get(data[2]))
```

Comment: I thought assign(data[1], dataset2) would assign into data[1] itself not to dataset found by its value. Apparently I was wrong

Comment: No, the more common `data[1] <- dataset2` would assign "into" data[1]